# How to limit the number of uses of a command (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I recently had to create a command to add a role to register for an event, however I would need to be able, using another command, to limit the number of uses of the first command.

Example: If I write !limit-inscriptions 20, I want the !inscrit command to be used only 20 times.

The problem being that I'm a beginner and I have no idea how to do the !limit-inscriptions command. So I'm calling you if you have any ideas on how to do it. Here is my (functional) code of the !inscrit command:

```js
 if(message.content === '!inscrit') {
        message.delete();
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Inscrit");

        if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Inscrit")) {
            message.member.removeRole(role)
            message.reply('vient de se désinscrire!')
        }
        else {
            message.member.addRole(role)
            message.reply(`vient de s'inscrire!`)
        }
    }
```

Comment: First you need to create a handler for the limit command.  Then you need to have a place to store the count for each person (use their ID, not their name!), such as a JSON object.  Finally if you will need to write that information to some kind of database if you want it to persist should your bot be restarted, it can be as simple as a file or as complicated as SQL.  If you have trouble, come back and show us what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

it's a good idea but I would like to host the bot on Heroku so I can't really, here is the beginning of the modification of the code of the command !inscrit, unfortunately this one doesn't work (I first wanted to put the limit from the command !inscrit then I would do it with the command !limit-inscriptions) :

```
var participants = 1;
var nbInscrit = 0;
if (message.content === '!inscrit') {
     message.delete();
     let role = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Inscrit");

     if (nbInscrit < participants) {

       if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Inscrit")) {
         message.member.removeRole(role)
         nbInscrit = nbInscrit - 1
         message.reply('vient de se désinscrire!')
       }
       else {
         message.member.addRole(role)
         nbInscrit = nbInscrit + 1
         message.reply("vient de s'inscrire!")
       }
     } else {
       message.channel.send('Le nombre Maximal de Participants est déjà atteint!');
     }
   }
```